# For the bound state to exist why must the potential $V(x)$ have at least one minimum which is lower than $V_1$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, schroedinger-equation

In chapter 4 of Zettili's book [Quantum Mechanics Concepts and Applications](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Quantum-Mechanics-Concepts-Applications-2nd/dp/0470026790) he shows this figure:

[image: Figure 4.1]

Then states:

> For the bound states to exist, the potential $V(x)$ must have at least one minimum which is lower than $V_1$ (i.e., $V_{\textrm{min}} \lt V_1$).

What does this mean?

Comment: What is $V_1$ here?

Comment: This isn't even a quantum mechanics issue, really. Just think about the case where a classical particle has energy $E$ as in the picture. Then imagine what would happen if there was no such dip, so that necessarily $E > V_1$. What would the particle do in that case?

Comment: by definition the motion of a particle in a bound state must be bounded...

Answer (score 1):

This question comes from section 4.2, “Properties of One-Dimensional Motion,” of the textbook of Zettili, which concerns a potential that

- Starts at $V_1$ as  $x\to{-\infty}$
- Attains some minimum $V_\text{min}< V_1$, without loss of generality at $x=0$, and,
- Then increases to some $V_2>V_1$ as $x \to {+\infty}$.

The question asked here is, why do we require $V_\text{min}< V_1$ for the existence of a bound state?

I will try to give an intuitive explanation.

### Life at infinity

Let's look at the time-independent Schrödinger equation,
$$
{\hbar^2\over2m}~\psi''(x) = [V(x) - E]~\psi(x).
$$
Now, if all of the interesting physical action happens for $-L<x<L$, you are tempted as a physicist to look in that range and then this equation might feel daunting. But an applied mathematician might say, “well, let's look at the vast vast majority of the number line, half of which is at $x < -10^{100} L$ and the other half is at $x > 10^{100} L.$ Sure there's some stuff happening between those two points but that's only finite, most of the number line is out towards infinity!” At these extremes, for these sorts of potentials, $V(x)=V_{1} $ or $V(x)=V_2$ basically become constant functions and this equation is just our friend the exponential/sinusoidal equation,
$$
\psi(x) = A e^{ikx},\\
\frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m} = E - V_{1,2}.
$$
If $E$ is greater than $V_1$ or $V_2$ then $k^2$ is positive in that region and this describes a sine wave $A e^{ikx}$ out towards $\pm \infty$. When we combine with the time dependence and both valid solutions we will get $A e^{i(kx-\omega t)}+B e^{i({-k}x-\omega t)}$, a superposition of moving plane waves with the same definite momentum $\hbar k$ moving to the left or the right. These are *very useful* but they are not *normalizable*. In particular, in scattering matrix theory you will set for $x\to -\infty$ the solution $A=1$, $B=r$, and for $x\to \infty$ you will set $A=t, B=0$ for unknown *reflection and transmission amplitudes* $r,t$. This pattern now has a bit of *causality* baked into it, it tells a story. “A unit plane wave is coming in from negative infinity to the system, and part of it gets transmitted and part of it gets reflected.”

If you want something normalizable
then you need exponential decay out towards infinity, not sinusoidal motion. And that can only happen when $E$ (which remember is the same on all sides, this is the time-independent Schrödinger equation, $E$ is a constant) is less than both $V_1$ and $V_2$, to force $k^2$ to be negative on both extremes, so that then $k$ is imaginary, so $e^{ikx}$ becomes an exponential growth or decay again. And this is a bound state.

### The need for oscillation

We are almost ready for the final puzzle piece in this intuitive explanation of what would be a formal mathematical proof in a more thorough textbook. To have a bound state we can see that we need $E<V_1$ and $E<V_2$ otherwise the asymptotic behavior towards infinity is oscillatory. But why does that detail about $E$ force *anything* out of $V(x)$? And there's something physical at stake here too, which is that if you could drive the energy down arbitrarily far, you would have negative kinetic energy, you would have unlimited amounts of free energy maybe, something isn't physically right about choosing arbitrarily low $E$.

Here's the key: at minus-infinity, we do not need just any solution: we need the one where $k$ is minus-imaginary, so that the dependence is $A e^{+kx}$ and the exponential decays to zero. But at plus-infinity, we need the solution where $k$ is plus-imaginary, the dependence is $A e^{-kx}$, and the exponential decays to zero that way.

So if $E$ is less than the minimum of $V(x)$ over $(-\infty,\infty)$, whether that is $V_1$ or $V_2$ or some $V_\text{min}$ in between, the Schrödinger equation becomes
$$
\psi''(x) = p(x)~\psi(x)
$$
for a strictly positive function $p(x).$ And the theorem is, that this grows without bound as you go to one of $\pm\infty$, it has a “gap” if you like between states of positive-imaginary $k$ and negative-imaginary $k$ and so if it decays at $-\infty$, because $k$ never gets to cross over that gap the function ultimately blows up at $+\infty$: or vice versa, you can make it decay on the right but it blows up on the left.

So all of these states are nonphysical and we have a theorem: The energy eigenvalue $E$ in the Schrödinger equation is always greater than the minimum of the potential $V(x)$ across the range it is defined. You need a region of space where the wave function oscillates, to bridge between the exponential decay on either side.

And *therefore*, once you know that for a bound state you have an $E$ satisfying both $E<V_1$ and $E<V_2$, you know that for a bound state there must be a $V_\text{min}$ lower than both of them, because if $E$ is less than all $V(x)$ you now know that there is no state at all. And in the contrapositive, if the potential stays strictly between $V_1$ and $V_2$ with no internal minimum, there is no bound state.